# The size of Highchart doesn't increase height of the chart more than 400px

Tags: flutter, highcharts

I trying to implement flutter chart using high_chart: ^2.0.3 Plugin. In web the size of the chart works fine but in Android app the size of the chart doesn't increase when I set size: Size(400, 600). It is fixed to size: Size(400, 400)

```
@override   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: const Text('High Charts Example App'),
      ),
      body: HighCharts(
        loader: const SizedBox(
          child: LinearProgressIndicator(),
          width: 200,
        ),
        size: Size(400, 600),
        data: _chartData,
        scripts: const [
          "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highstock/6.0.3/highstock.js",
          'https://code.highcharts.com/modules/networkgraph.js',
          'https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js',
        ],
      ),
    );   }
```

Comment: Can you format code with ```

Comment: Be aware that the HighChart products used by some packages in the Dart/Flutter pub are *not* open source.  They are released under a commercial license that may subject you or your organization to a financial liability, and might affect downstream re-users of your code.